# What is the simplest way to calculate this determinant using properties of determinants?

Tags: determinant

A=$\begin{bmatrix} \frac ab & \frac bc & \frac ca\\a & b & c\\ab & bc & ca\end{bmatrix}$

Or maby there is no shorcut to calculate the det(A)?

Comment: It seems that Sarrus rule is good enough

Comment: You can divide the first column by $a/b$, the second one by $b/c$, the third one by $c/a$, since the product of these numbers is $1$, the determinant is unchanged but the matrix has a better-known form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform $C_3\to C_3-(c/b)C_2,C_2\to C_2-(b/a)C_1$,
$$\sim\begin{vmatrix} \frac ab & \frac bc-1& \frac ca-1\\a &0 & 0\\ab & b(c-b) & c(a-c)\end{vmatrix}$$Now, factor out $a,(b-c),(c-a)$ from the first three columns respectively,$$\sim a(c-a)(b-c)
\begin{vmatrix} \frac 1b & \frac 1c& \frac 1a\\1 &0 & 0\\b &-b& -c\end{vmatrix}$$and expand along the second row to get the answer $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.